# Run snippet of jquery code on a specific webpage from a local module

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, localhost

I have a short snippet of jquery code that I use to pick and submit a specific choice in a drop-down menu on a website.

For now, I've pasted the code into the console, but I would like to set up some form of simple local module with a button, that when clicked runs the jquery code on the specific website.

I don't know much coding aside from a bit VBA, so I'm unsure what's the best way to go about this. Intuitively, I imagine that it shouldn't be that difficult of a task, but I can't quite wrap my head around how I set it up and if it's even possible to click a button in a local module that then performs an action on a webpage.

Really hoping some of you might be able to give me some guidance. Any help is appreciated!

Best regards
Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, I would like to do this in VBA, but i'm unsure if it's possible to run jquery scripts from VBA. I'm using Chrome Browser by the way.